# Looking for GeoPandas QGIS equivalent of ArcGIS "Select by location" tool

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, select-by-location, point-in-polygon

I have two GeoDataFrames:

1. A single multi-part polygon
2. Many points

I have read them in with the following:

```py
import geopandas as gpd

poly = gpd.read_file('C:\\Users\\srcha\\Desktop\\folder\\poly.shp')
points = gpd.read_file('c:\\Users\\srcha\\Desktop\\folder\\points.shp')
```

I want to run the equivalent of "Select by location" in ArcGIS with GeoPandas and shapely tools to select points that are within the polygon.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If `poly` is a GeoDataFrame with a single geometry, extract this:

```
polygon = poly.geometry[0]
```

Then, you can use the `within` method to check which points are within the polygon:

```
points.within(polygon)
```

returning a boolean True/False values which can be used to filter the original dataframe:

```
subset = points[points.within(polygon)]
```

Answer (score 5):

In case the polygon layer contains many polygon features, the solution can be extended, like so:

```
poly = gpd.read_file('C:/Users/srcha/Desktop/folder/poly.shp')
points = gpd.read_file('c:/Users/srcha/Desktop/folder/points.shp')

poly['dummy'] = 'dummy'  # add dummy column to dissolve all geometries into one
geom = poly.dissolve(by='dummy').geometry[0]  # take the single union geometry
subset = points[points.within(geom)]
```

I'm not fond of the dummy-trick, but I have no other idea how to do this using geopandas.

Answer (score 4):

It is much faster if you use spatial join:

```
subset = gpd.sjoin(points, polygon, how='inner', op='within')
```

GeoPandas Version 0.10.0 or later:

```
subset = gpd.sjoin(points, polygon, how='inner', predicate='within')
```

Answer (score 3):

If you convert the poly boundary GeoDataFrame to a single polygon, eg with:

```
poly_union = poly.geometry.unary_union
```

then you can use boolean filtering with the within operator to select points within and outside of poly_union:

```
within_poly_union = points[points.geometry.within(poly_union)]
outside_poly_union = points[~points.geometry.within(poly_union)]
```

Alternatively, you could use the disjoint spatial predicate:

```
outside_poly_union = points[points.geometry.disjoint(poly_union)]
inside_poly_union = points[~points.geometry.disjoint(poly_union)]
```

Answer derived from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52608107/10664022)