# Generate points inside multipolygons using GeoPandas

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, geoseries

I have a shapefile which has multipolygon geometries. I want to generate random points inside them using GeoPandas. I tried with the below code but it's not giving geodataframe of points.

```
df = gpd.read_file(multipolygonshp)
geom= df['geometry']
final_geom = geom.unary_union
x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max = final_geom.bounds

n = 3000
x = np.random.uniform(x_min, x_max, n)
y = np.random.uniform(y_min, y_max, n)

gdf_points = gpd.GeoSeries(gpd.points_from_xy(x, y))
gdf_points = gpd.GeoSeries(gdf_points.within(final_geom.unary_union))

<ipython-input-125-ed976bd8ef24>:23: FutureWarning:     You are passing non-geometry data to the GeoSeries constructor. Currently,
    it falls back to returning a pandas Series. But in the future, we will start
    to raise a TypeError instead.
  gdf_points = gpd.GeoSeries(gdf_points.within(final_geom))
```

Comment: So the problem is you get a geoseries when you want a dataframe? How many multipolygons do you want to generate random points for? How important is it to get a certain number of points?

Comment: No I'm just getting the boolen values not the points in a geodataframe(gdf_points). I have 30+ polygon geometries inside the shapefile and I just want few points inside each geometry not necessary to have certain number of points.

Comment: You would be fine if some polygons don't have any point?

Comment: No I need points inside each polygon @til_b

Answer (score 2):

[FutureWarning](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#FutureWarning) is a simple warnings statement that you can eliminate with

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
```

The result of `gdf_points.within` is a Boolean, as you say ([shapely binary predicates](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#binary-predicates))

```
gdf_points = gpd.GeoSeries(gdf_points.within(final_geom))
gdf_points.head(5)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
 dtype: bool
```

And it is a Pandas serie (not a GeoSerie -> no geometry)

```
type(gdf_points)
pandas.core.series.Series
```

There are many solutions in GIS SE and I use here [Geopandas equivalent to select by location](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/279675/2581)

```
gdf_points = gpd.GeoSeries(gpd.points_from_xy(x, y))
subset = gdf_points[gdf_points.within(final_geom)]
subset.head(5)
2     POINT (0.49117 -0.09817)
5     POINT (-0.51586 -0.68984)
8     POINT (-0.42499 0.01249)
10    POINT (-0.21973 -0.35859)
11    POINT (-0.77146 0.17700)
dtype: geometry

type(subset)
geopandas.geoseries.GeoSeries
```

Look also [Check if a point falls within a multipolygon with Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/208574/2581) with GeoDataFrames, for example

```
gdf_points = gpd.GeoSeries(gpd.points_from_xy(x, y))
points = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':gdf_points})
poly = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':final_geom})
within_points = gpd.sjoin(points, poly, op = 'within')
within_points.head(5)
        geometry             index_right
2   POINT (0.49117 -0.09817)    0
14  POINT (0.66375 -0.09176)    0
17  POINT (0.55135 -0.36559)    0
39  POINT (0.69521 -0.37174)    0
59  POINT (0.60061 -0.29019)    0
```

Comment: Filtering the warning is not a solution, because it will return an error in the next release.

Comment: @gene I tried the above methods as suggested by you, it is hardly give me any points(like 5-10) put together.

Answer (score 1):

You may also try to buffer the df to avoid self-intersection in multi-polygons layers:

```
df = gpd.read_file(multipolygonshp)

# buffering to avoid self-intersection in multipolygons layers
df = geom.buffer(0.1)

# Use GeoSeries.total_bounds if you would like the limits of the entire series
x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max = df.total_bounds

n = 3000
x = np.random.uniform(x_min, x_max, n)
y = np.random.uniform(y_min, y_max, n)

gdf_points = gpd.GeoSeries(gpd.points_from_xy(x, y))

# You can directly retrieve the points that intersect the polygon
gdf_points = gdf_points[gdf_points.within(gdf_points.unary_union)]

gdf_points

0       POINT (318400.364 5064051.518)
1       POINT (264133.118 5067828.107)
2       POINT (307008.396 5090454.061)
3       POINT (287648.343 5091872.906)
4       POINT (275455.794 5068725.441)
                     ...              
2995    POINT (265071.293 5082035.520)
2996    POINT (300584.749 5085800.227)
2997    POINT (316275.872 5093292.001)
2998    POINT (308961.236 5093976.585)
2999    POINT (283761.834 5062090.378)
Length: 3000, dtype: geometry
```